# MongoDB:How to call an external function you load with load funcion?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I created a simple java script with a function.

I'm named `Create(X)` that execute `db.mycollect.insert` 
`x` times inside in a `for` loop.

When i executed `load` function on `mongo` shell it runs correct.
Then when i execute `Create(10)` for example.
It doesn't create the `10` new documents.

My steps are:

- I create a simple script,

like this:

```
function Create(x)
{ 
    db.runCommand("use mycollect");
    for(i=i;i<x;i++)
    { 
         db.departaments.insert([{"id":i,"name":"IT","acces":"T"}])
    }
}
```

- I ran load("simple.js").It returns true
- And finally i ran Create(10). It seems corrects
- But when i ran db.departments.find().The collection is void.

If the response could be in simple english or spanish i'll apreccite it.

```
<--Solution-->
```

The answer was on the script.

It was an error as user jao said.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: for(i=i, ...) -> isn't it supposed to be i=0?

Comment: I copy incorrectly the javascript but the error was similar to this jao.

Comment: `db.runCommand("use mycollect")` is not valid in the shell. Can you create and run this function directly in the shell?

Comment: No i'm new in this wberkley. You are right in there.But the error was on the script as jao said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`db.getSiblingDB('<db>')`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo) to switch to a database.

```
function Create(x)
{ 
    db = db.getSiblingDB('mycollect');
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
    { 
         db.departaments.insert([{"id":i,"name":"IT","acces":"T"}])
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i try getSiblingDB  thanks BatScream. The error was on my script as user japo says.